# Option to restrict non-admin licensed users to create PowerApps environments

Tags: powerapps, common-data-service

Is there any way to restrict licensed users from creating environments? According to Microsoft documentation, Users who have PowerApps or Flow P2 license, they can come to Admin Center and create environments for them. Also users with the Community plan license can also create one Developer environment. But we want users to create canvas and model driven apps and other facilities which comes with PowerApps license, but we do not want them to create environments. If the users create environments, there will be so many environments which are very difficult to administer (the issue which we are facing right now). We want specific environments created by admins to be used by all the users. Is there any way to restrict normal users from creating environments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/control-environment-creation) says:

1. Sign in to the Power Platform Admin center at https://admin.powerplatform.microsoft.com
2. Select the Gear icon in the upper-right corner of the Power Platform site
3. Select “Only specific admins”

[image]

The following admins will be able to create new environments in the Power Platform Admin center:

- Office 365 Global admins
- Service admins
- Delegated admins